# json.dumps on dictionary with bytes for keys

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Trying to convert dictionary object with keys of type bytes to json using json.dumps(). Format of dictionary object is not known beforehand. Have found solution for arrays or dictionaries with byte values when using json.dumps ([Convert bytes embedded in list (or dict) to str for use with json.dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56874045/convert-bytes-embedded-in-list-or-dict-to-str-for-use-with-json-dumps)) but have not found one for byte keys.

```
import json

class BytesDump(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, bytes):
            return obj.decode()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

foo = {'name': b'bob', 'age': 33, 'attributes': {'hair': b'brown', 'arms': 2}}
bar = {b'name': b'bob', b'age': 33, b'attributes': {b'hair': b'brown', b'arms': 2}}

print(json.dumps(foo, cls=BytesDump)) # this works
print(json.dumps(bar, cls=BytesDump)) # this doesn't work
```

Output  from above

```
{"name": "bob", "age": 33, "attributes": {"hair": "brown", "arms": 2}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(json.dumps(bar, cls=BytesDump))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
TypeError: keys must be a string
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could pre-process the dictionary to convert the keys as strings recursively if they're bytes

```
import json
# your dump code for values, unmodified
class BytesDump(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, bytes):
            return obj.decode()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

# recursive key as string conversion for byte keys
def keys_string(d):
    rval = {}
    if not isinstance(d, dict):
        if isinstance(d,(tuple,list,set)):
            v = [keys_string(x) for x in d]
            return v
        else:
            return d

    for k,v in d.items():
        if isinstance(k,bytes):
            k = k.decode()
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            v = keys_string(v)
        elif isinstance(v,(tuple,list,set)):
            v = [keys_string(x) for x in v]
        rval[k] = v
    return rval

print(json.dumps(keys_string(bar), cls=BytesDump))
```

with:

```
bar = {b'name': b'bob', b'age': 33, b'attributes': {b'hair': b'brown', b'arms': 2},
b'other': [{b'hair': b'brown', b'arms': 2}]}
```

prints:

```
{"attributes": {"hair": "brown", "arms": 2}, "age": 33, "name": "bob", "other": [{"hair": "brown", "arms": 2}]}
```

Comment: I got an error : `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'` https://stackoverflow.com/q/58019389/2897115. I had a`dict_try = '_preconf_set_by_auto': {'result_backend', 'broker_url'}` and tried `keys_string(dict_try)`. It gave error. `elif isinstance(v,(tuple,list,set)):
            v = [keys_string(x) for x in v]` is causing the problem

Comment: okay, maybe my code hasn't 100% coverage. Let me check that in the weekend. Thanks

Comment: Your recursive function assumes the input is always a dict. it is not,  I added `if not isinstance(d, dict): return d` before `for k,v in d.items():` then it worked thank you

Comment: I have edi bit different, considering sometimes it can be `[ [ {}, {}, ],'string',[ 'string',{}, etc ]  ]` array of array of objects

Comment: recently i have encountered another problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59662479/python-error-dictionary-changed-size-during-iteration-when-trying-to-iterate

For that i have to copy the keys in a list and then iterate. else it give error that `dictionary changed size during iteration`. So i have edited accordingly

Comment: okay, but in that very case, I don't see how it could happen, as `rval` is not `d`. Are you sure?

Comment: `rval[k]=v` How it will be `d`

Comment: the type of the keys change, so we need to create _another_ dictionary than `d`, so iterate on `d` and update `rval`

Comment: sorry i could get you. We are  `iterate on d and update rval`

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you need to use a recursive utility function to traverse the dictionary and convert the keys and values it encounters along the way that are bytes into strings:

```
import json

def decode_dict(d):
    result = {}
    for key, value in d.items():
        if isinstance(key, bytes):
            key = key.decode()
        if isinstance(value, bytes):
            value = value.decode()
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            value = decode_dict(value)
        result.update({key: value})
    return result


bar = {b'name': b'bob', b'age': 33, b'attributes': {b'hair': b'brown', b'arms': 2}}
print(json.dumps(decode_dict(bar)))
```

Output:

```
{"name": "bob", "age": 33, "attributes": {"hair": "brown", "arms": 2}}
```