# python: Error: dictionary changed size during iteration @ when trying to iterate over django request object at SimpleLazyObject

Tags: python, django, dictionary

In python in a dictionary if `key` is `byte string` then `json.dumps` will throw error, So I am trying to convert recursively all the `keys` as `string` before passing them to `json.dumps`.

```
Note: json.dumps converts the value to str using default function but not keys
```

The following is my function which will check for any `byte string keys` and convert them to `string`:

```
def keys_string(d):
    rval = {}
    if not isinstance(d, dict):
        if isinstance(d,(tuple,list,set)):
            v = [keys_string(x) for x in d]
            return v
        else:
            return d
    for k,v in d.items():
        if isinstance(k,bytes):
            k = k.decode()
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            v = keys_string(v)
        elif isinstance(v,(tuple,list,set)):
            v = [keys_string(x) for x in v]
        rval[k] = v
    return rval
```

I am debugging some code in django

I want to check the `request` object at certain point of my code

So i have

```
request_dir = dir(request)
```

then convert any byte keys to string using `keys_string` (Else json dumps will throw error)

```
request_dir_keys_stringed = keys_string(request_dir)
```

Then finally

```
json.dumps(request_dir_keys_stringed, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
```

When i am trying to do  `request_dir_keys_stringed = keys_string(request_dir)` it says

```
in keys_string
    for k,v in d.items():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

I found this happening when:

`k: user` and `v: <SimpleLazyObject: <User: test@gmail.com>>`

I tried for `request.session` object it does not throw such error. But some object do.

```
request_session_dir = dir(request.session)
request_session_dir_keys_stringed = keys_string(request_session_dir)
json.dumps(request_session_dir_keys_stringed, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
```

What to do in such situations

**More info to reproduce the issue:**

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.3

$ django-admin --version
2.2.6

def articles(request):
    request_dir = dir(request)
    request_dir_keys_stringed = keys_string(request_dir)
    print(json.dumps(request_dir_keys_stringed, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
    return render(request, 'articles/main_page/articles.html')
```

**AFTER IMPLEMENTING THE SOLUTION THE keys_string becomes:**

```
def keys_string(d):
    rval = {}
    if not isinstance(d, dict):
        if isinstance(d,(tuple,list,set)):
            v = [keys_string(x) for x in d]
            return v
        else:
            return d
    keys = list(d.keys())
    for k in keys:
        v = d[k]
        if isinstance(k,bytes):
            k = k.decode()
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            v = keys_string(v)
        elif isinstance(v,(tuple,list,set)):
            v = [keys_string(x) for x in v]
        rval[k] = v
    return rval


        request_dir = dir(request)
        request_dir_keys_stringed = keys_string(request_dir)
        print(json.dumps(request_dir_keys_stringed, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
```

And now request object is shown without any errors

Comment: Python and Django version please ? (could not reproduce the issue here).

Comment: I have added the info in the edited question

Comment: Doesn't ```dir(request)``` always return a ```list```? So your code never reaches the ```for``` loop?

Comment: Can someone actually reproduce the issue with the OP's code ? `dir()` returns a list of strings, so I fail to see how it could enter the `for k,v in d.items()` part. @SanthoshYedidi either the code you posted is not the code that actually raises this error, or the builtin `dir` function is, at this point, shadowed by something else. Please add `print(dir)` at the beginning of your function and post what it prints.

Comment: Yes, It can be a list, but the list can be set of objects. like [ 'someitem,[{},{}],{},etc] So the first time it may not enter the loop but when goe deeper it should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.user` is `SimpleLazyObject` which holds a callback that is a closure which holds a reference to same `request` object. And then that callback updates `request` object by creating new attr `request._cached_user` if it does not exist. So observing `request.user` would possibly create a new `request._cached_user` attribute.

A think it is easier to explain it with code excerpts.

From django source code:

```py
class SimpleLazyObject(LazyObject):
    def __init__(self, func):
        ...

class AuthenticationMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))

def get_user(request):
    if not hasattr(request, '_cached_user'):
        request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
    return request._cached_user
```

So if you want to have more stable walk through dictionary keys then you need to iterate over dict's keys copy:

```py
keys = list(d.keys())
for k in keys:
    v = d[k]
    if isinstance(k, bytes):
        ...
```

Comment: `dir()` returns a list of strings... How could the OP's function ever access `request.user` from a list of strings ? (nb: doesn't mean you're on the wrong track - I actually suspect the op's `dir()` is not the builtin one - just that given the OP's snippet the whole thing just doesn't make sense).

Comment: I read in some answers that d.items() also copies the keys. So then thats not true. This worked perfectly great. It saved my day. Thanks @petraszd.

Comment: _dir() returns a list of strings_

Yeah. But if you pass that `list` to `keys_string` than at line 5 it is going call `keys_string` for each item. One of the items is going to be `HttpRequest`'s instance's `__dict__`.